# StartActivity wont work from onclick event

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-facebook

i'm trying to log in with facebook and pass the user's info to another activity
The problem is when i run the startActivity method with the intent the onclick event gets freeze's and doesn't do anything

I created a class that implements Serializable that holds a couple of strings

then when the user log in with facebook i create an instance of that class so i can pass it on to the other activity

heres the code:

```
Session.openActiveSession(me, true, new StatusCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
            {
                if(session.isOpened())
                {
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                        {
                             if(user!=null)
                             {      
                                GraphLocation location= user.getLocation();
                                String address = location.getStreet()+","+location.getCity()+","+location.getState()+","+location.getCountry();
                                b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                 Fuser = new FBuser(
                                        user.getName(),
                                        user.getFirstName(),
                                        user.getLastName(),
                                        user.getBirthday(),
                                        user.getId(),
                                        user.getInnerJSONObject(),
                                        user.getLink(),
                                        address,
                                        user.getUsername());


                             }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

as you can see I set a button to be visible and when the user clicks the button i start the activity and pass with it the user object:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                final Login log = (Login) me;

                final FBuser user = Fuser;
                final Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Profile.class);
                i.putExtra("user", user);
                try 
                {
                log.startActivity(i);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.getMessage();
                }                                       
            }
        });

    }
```

But nothing happends the button freeze's and nothing happends.

Any ideas why this could happend?

Comment: What is "me" and is Login extending Activity? And by the way, you shouldn't use getBaseContext(), use <EnclosingActivityName>.this instead.

Comment: Theres no errors in the logcat.  and yes Login extends activity I will tried using Login.this but it doesnt work

Comment: Are you filtering the logcat? If so, you may be missing something valuable/useful. Have another look.

Comment: Post the code that sets the variable "me" to something.